# how to make a moving background in javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I go about creating something like this guys website? http://paradoxsprx.net/

like the dots and the lines move when your mouse moves?

Comment: Show us some code so we can see what you've tried.

Comment: Did you even try looking at how he did it?

Comment: Take a look at the paradoxsprx website's source code, it's not minified: http://paradoxsprx.net/js/scripts.js – he's using a large canvas in the background of the page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have got a solution for you. This example is more similar to your's one. You can download the source code and use it.

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/09/23/animated-background-headers/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it was made with [Particles.js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/)

Might be useful to look into that library as well!

Answer (score -1):

It's canvas element.
WebGL

For 3D effects you could start by learning ThreeJS Library.

Comment: the URL the OP mentioned does not use ThreeJS, though…

Answer (score -2):

## HI!

If you **inspect** that page code, you'll see **canvas** element.

**canvas** is an element that is similar to **img** but instead of displaying an image, it provides you a context that you can draw on.

You do not need to use any libraries to play with it, and i'd suggest you just to learn **2d context** first.

**here you can learn more about canvas** https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

---

I hope that my answer is somewhat useful to you!